# Connector datasheet is in chinese. Which part is which?

Tags: connector

I have just a couple of questions...

1. Is the "male" side the one with the male contacts or the male contact shroud?
2. I'm also looking for the PNs for a 2 circuit configuration of the housing on the left side of the page.  I presume the number in parentheses is the PN for the contact and the left most table at bottom has the PN for the housing.

[image]

Comment: male is usually with a pin-type contacts, the female is with receptacle contacts. Pretty intuitive, I would say..

Comment: @EugeneSh. is correct. Pins = male, sockets = female. Doesn't matter what the shroud is doing.

Comment: BTW, the google translate from camera on my smartphone is working surprisingly well with this page.

Comment: Apparently it's not allowed to post an answer containing Chinese characters. This is going to make it hard to give certain kinds of answers.

Comment: There are similar alternatives from Molex, Tyco and the other usual suspects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the top left: "Negative Connecting Clamp".

Middle left: "Negative Connector"

Bottom: "Installation Dimensions/Measurements"

Top Right: "Positive Connector"

Left Table: "Socket",        Right Table: "Plug"

Inside the tables, you have "Cable number", "Model Number" and then the dimensions in mm.